# Connecting two computers over serial

Tags: linux, networking, usb, serial-port, serial

I have previously used my Arduinos to program other devices over serial by connecting the Arduino to my computer, grounding RES, and connecting the TX and RX pins on each device. This allows me to bypass the ATmega328 chip, and send data directly to the device connected to the Arduino.

Today I decided to install Ubuntu Server on a headless Raspberry Pi using a serial console via two Arduinos connected to each other. Before I started installing the system, I decided to try the idea on my laptop - I grounded the RES pins on both, connected their ground, TX and RX pins to each other (RX to TX and vice versa) and plugged both into a separate USB port (no hubs involved, internally or externally). I then started picocom for both devices in separate terminals:

```
sudo picocom -b 38400 /dev/ttyUSB0
sudo picocom -b 38400 /dev/ttyUSB1
```

and tried to send a message from one device to the other, but despite having the TX LED on the transmitting, and the RX on the receiving device flash, no data is displayed in picocom.

I ran `dmesg | grep tty` to confirm that the devices are connected and, as expected, I get the following output:

```
[15085.910703] usb 1-1.2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[15086.258910] usb 1-1.3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

with no error messages.

This isn't a problem with picocom either, as I have tried minicom and screen as well as `echo <message> | sudo tee /dev/ttyUSB0`, all to no avail.

Am I missing something here? Is it even possible to do this?

EDIT: I have tried removing the second Arduino, using a circuit like this:
[image]
But, as before, the RX and TX lights flash, but nothing shows up on the serial monitor

Comment: Do both serials use the same voltage levels? The serial ports you can find on embedded devices today use a wide range of different voltages.

Comment: @dirkt Yes, both devices are identical.

Comment: Next thing I'd try is to reduce baud rate (try several of the lowest settings. Do you have a scope or similar to monitor the signals?